# autodoc of python decorator wrapped functions in a file

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators, autodoc

I searched and searched for a solution where I can use Sphinx `autodoc` to find all the decorator wrapped functions in my Python script/file. The script contains a number of functions all called `step_impl` with different parameters, but each wrapped by a different unique decorator. I want to be able to document these as separate functions. Currently it is only picking the last function in the script.

Here is what the script looks like:

```
@given(u'I am testing a browser')
def step_impl(context):
    """STEP: I am testing a browser
    :param context: webdriver context
    :type context: dictionary
    """
    <stuff here>

@when(u'I visit "{browser_page}"')
def step_impl(context, browser_page):
    <other stuff here>

@then(u'I see the Top Rail')
def step_impl(context):
    context.page.assert_element_display("id", "adv_header")
    <still other stuff here>
```

So I have the `.rst` file with the `automodule` formatting:

```
.. automodule:: features.steps.general
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

And the documentation only lists one function as:

```
features.steps.general.step_impl(context, title_text, element_type, element_name)
```

which happens to be the last function in the script.

How can I have the decorator listed for each function and list all functions even if they have the same name. I tried to understand `functools.wraps`, but couldn't get my head 'wrapped' around it (see what I did there!!).

Thank you for any guidance in advance....

Comment: IMHO you should not have multiple functions with the same name and I doubt Sphinx can handle it "correclty". If your functions do different stuff, they should have different names. If they do the same thing, you should not have multiple functions.

Comment: I am using Behave which is how it setups up the steps within the framework.

Comment: I just took a look at the Behave documentation and the examples all use "step_impl" as function name, howeverI don't think it is a requirement. I think you can call the function as you wish. You should try.

Comment: @Tryph Hmmm.... never thought of that. I will try that, thank you.

Comment: In Behave you don't have to use 'step_impl' as a function name. Just use normal function naming convention. For better support in any IDE just use prefixes and descriptive name like: "@given(u'I am testing a browser')" use "def given_i_am_testing_a_browser".